# Is there a source for leaf-off aerial imagery?

Tags: data, imagery, remote-sensing, aerial-photography

I am looking for leaf-off imagery for Oklahoma, Kansas and Texas.  1m leaf-off imagery would be ideal, although any substitute would be helpful.  I need fairly high resolution imagery to distinguish conifer from deciduous trees--Landsat would likely be too coarse.  How can I obtain leaf-off imagery for KS, OK, TX?

Comment: Are you trying to do this tree by tree, or over large swaths?  You can usually distinguish this at the stand level using Landsat data and multi-spectral image classification methods.

Comment: @Jay I'm identifying individual trees over large areas, so higher resolution imagery would be beneficial.

Comment: Sounds like quite the undertaking!!

Answer (score 2):

Nationally, you could check the list of programs at http://www.ndop.gov/maintenance.html or http://pubs.usgs.gov/fs/2009/3055/pdf/FS2009-3055.pdf. At least 2 programs that fly leaf-off are listed.

You will probably find more current and higher-resolution options if you check with each state's natural resources, forestry, or emergency management agencies, and maybe state universities. They may fly their own leaf-off imagery or collect and consolidate imagery from other agencies or county governments. I started to find promising hits by googling things like 'texas leaf off imagery'...

Answer (score 1):

The National States Geographic Information Council (NSGIC) maintains a list of [GIS representatives for each State](http://www.nsgic.org/state-representatives). These rep's are often the GIS coordinator for their respective State, and as such they have alot of information about data availability. You could contact the rep's from those three States to ask if high-res leaf-off imagery is available, and how to obtain it.

Comment: Good idea. NSGIC has a DOP committee, and if other states are like my own, a state's DOP committee chair is probably also a liason to NDOP, and is probably the single best go-to person to find out what is available.

Answer (score 0):

Since the date of your question, Nearmap (go.nearmap.com) has been regularly flying US metro areas and they typically will capture both spring and fall leaf-off aerial imagery.

And yes, I work for them as well.