# Georeferencing DWG files on imagery which is hard to see through (e.g. trees)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing, imagery, dwg

Here I have a few campgrouds that I have for are in DWG files that I am going to georeference them. I have no problem with that however; some of these campgrounds I need to georeference on the imagery are pretty much covered with alot of trees and it is difficult to georeference it. Is there a way around that can I see "through" the trees where I can see the road under the trees? I have in my mind but the campgrounds are mostly on the Forest Service lands. Right now I am using the ESRI Basemap World Imagery. Most of the campground I found are able to identify easily. I need to do 3 of them. I checked other basemaps and they are not that good to see it.  Any ideas ?

Here is the example taken from picture[image]

Comment: What other basemaps have you tried? You might have some luck with the historical scenes from [USGS](http://www.usgs.gov/pubprod/aerial.html#aerial) and other places.

Comment: @Paul The only thing I have in my mind is the aerial photos and I will need to check on that one. Thanks for that thought !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from the question, it seems like you essentially want leaf-off aerial imagery (generally just imagery taken in the winter months if you are unfamiliar) to give you a better chance at seeing what is under the canopy .  I do not think any of the main ESRI streaming basemaps will get you what you need.

There are some free options out there that you can download and are hopefully in your study area but they may not have the fine spatial resolution that you require for digitizing.

This question:
[Is there a source for leaf-off aerial imagery?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55476/is-there-a-source-for-leaf-off-aerial-imagery) , is where I was able to find the following link that outlines a few sources of free imagery (assuming you are in the U.S.) and what their gorund conditions are:

http://www.ndop.gov/maintenance.html

I recommend using Earth Explorer to try to download a few imagery sets and see if they work for what you need.

http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

If you are unfamiliar with Earth Explorer you will want to:

**Search Criteria Tab**

Set the location to your study area and set the date range to search by winter months for your region.

**Data Sets Tab**

Expand the "Aerial Imagery menu then select "DOQ" and "High Resolution Orthoimagery (you can try others too, those are just my recommendations).

**Results**

Click the "Results" button or the tab and play around in the map with what comes up.  If they work, download them and check them out in ArcMap.